# Where is the "Fold" LINQ Extension Method?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, reduce

I found in [MSDN's Linq samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747.aspx#foldSimple) a neat method called Fold() that I want to use.  Their example:

```
double[] doubles = { 1.7, 2.3, 1.9, 4.1, 2.9 }; 
double product = 
     doubles.Fold((runningProduct, nextFactor) => runningProduct * nextFactor);
```

Unfortunately, I can't get this to compile, either in their example or in my own code, and I can't find anywhere else in MSDN (like Enumerable or Array extension methods) that mention this method.  The error I get is a plain old "don't know anything about that" error:

```
error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Fold' and no 
extension method 'Fold' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could 
be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm using other methods which I believe come from Linq (like Select() and Where()), and I'm "using System.Linq", so I think that's all OK.

Does this method really exist in C# 3.5, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check out the bread crumb trail* on the samples page you referenced--it refers to C# 3 as a future product. Future products often change before they ship. Like the others mentioned, see Enumerable.Aggregate and have fun. :)

*Visual C# Developer Center >  Home >  Product Information >  Future Versions >  101 LINQ Samples >  Aggregate Operators

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You will want to use the `Aggregate` extension method:

```
double product = doubles.Aggregate(1.0, (prod, next) => prod * next);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) for more information. It lets you specify a `seed` and then an expression to calculate successive values.

Comment: It should be noted that you don't have to have a seed, either. If you call the overload that has no seed then the first element in the list is used as the initial aggregate value and the `Func` is only called once the second element is reached. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It isn't fold if I am understand right :/ The fold should accepts both arguments of different types. E.g. one could as the first arg use a string, and as the second arg anything with `ToString()`, thus return a text representation of the whole container.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, no, the example is in fact a fold.  The `<double>` type parameter is just automatically inferred by the compiler and thus not necessary.

Comment: @kdbanman no, you didn't get what I meant, but in fact you're right — the example is a partial case of fold, although back in the moment when I left the comment, I was needed a bit more powerful fold. In *pseudo-C#* what I was needed would look like `array.Aggregate("", (p, elem) => String.Concat(p, elem.ToString()))`. But I don't think it's possible with C#'s weak type system. **UPD:** to be clearer: the pseudo-code example folds over an array with a function that takes a string as the first arg, and an element of the array as the second; thus making string representation of the container.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, `p` and `elem` can be whatever type you like.  See [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx) as used in [this example](http://csharppad.com/gist/725521c557b659f054df)

Comment: @kdbanman errr, ⁺¹, it is really interesting why back in the time it didn't work for me… :/ You're right, it does work.

Answer (score 43):

[Fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) (aka Reduce) is the standard term from functional programming.  For whatever reason, it got named [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) in LINQ.

```
double product = doubles.Aggregate(1.0, (runningProduct, nextFactor) => runningProduct* nextFactor);
```

Comment: Aggregate is a more familiar term in the OO and SQL realms.

Comment: Was not aware of the CREATE AGGREGATE keyword ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741.aspx )  Learn something new every day.

Comment: Funny, I've never heard "aggregate" outside of SQL.  WP has a list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function) of a couple dozen languages and C# is the only one that calls it "Aggregate".  "Reduce" is the clear winner, followed by "Fold" for the ML family, and "Inject" for Smalltalk and friends.

Comment: Another possible explanation for not being called fold is that fold generally implies a recursive operation. Linq is mostly implemented with iterators.

Comment: The name is a matter of its functionality; how it is implemented is irrelevant. And FWIW, left folds are implemented iteratively when possible ... in functional languages usually via tail recursion. And C# doesn't have a right fold, which is in part a consequence of picking a stupid name -- though not as bad as "select" for "map" -- and ignoring existing functional technology. As for Aggregate being a more familiar term in the OO realm ... no, not at all.

Comment: To be fair, I don't think it's Microsoft's disregard of existing functional technology or terminology, but its orientation towards database access and SQL's terminology, which many enterprise programmers are probably more familiar with than functional programming terms.

Comment: To be fair Aggregate has two overloads, one for traditional Fold, and another for Reduce.  F# has done the service of actually splitting these apart and naming them properly.