# LINQ changing local "let" variable

Tags: c#, linq, variables

Using a LINQ query (with C#) how would I go about do something like this (pseudocode)?

I'd look to do something like this is in places where, for example, I might generate 1000's of lists of 100's of random (bounded) integers, where I want to track the smallest of them as they're generated.

```
Best <- null value 

Foreach N in Iterations
    NewList <- List of 100 randomly generated numbers
    If Best is null
        Best <- NewList

    If Sum(NewList) < Sum(Best)
        Best <- NewList

Select Best
```

I've tried all sorts of things, but I can't really get it working. This isn't for any kind of project or work, just for my own curiosity!

Example of what I was thinking:

```
let R = new Random()   
let Best = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(S => R.Next(-100, 100)).ToArray()

//Where this from clause is acting like a for loop 
from N in Iterations 
    let NewList = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(S => R.Next(-100, 100))
    Best = (NewList.Sum() < Best.Sum())? NewList : Best;

select Best
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the minimum value in a collection?  If so, how about collection.Min()?

Comment: That sort of thing, in this situation, yes. I'm trying to implement different algorithms using LINQ alone, as a challenge.

Comment: You actually want `let Best = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(S => R.Next(-100, 100)).ToArray()` -- otherwise you would get a new set of random numbers every time you look at its contents.

Comment: BTW, `NewList` has the same problem. Also, `ToList()` is a similar way to solve it.

Comment: NewList would need to be a different set of random numbers on each iteration, so I'm not sure casting is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) (aka "reduce") which is known as [Aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230729/where-is-the-fold-linq-extension-method) in LINQ.

([IEnumerable.Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352408.aspx)/Max are special-cases, but can be written in terms of fold/Aggregate.)

```
int Max (IEnumerable<int> x) {
  return x.Aggregate(int.MinValue, (prev, cur) => prev > cur ? prev : cur);
}
Max(new int[] { 1, 42, 2, 3 }); // 42
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Excellent example, thanks. I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for, but it's certainly helped me understand aggregates better.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're just selecting the minimum value.

```
var minimum = collection.Min( c => c );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively finding the minimum value in the collection, if it exists:

```
int? best = null;
if (collection != null && collection.Length > 0) best = collection.Min();
```

Comment: My example was bad, sorry. I've added a better explanation of why I might want to do something like that, which hopefully explains why I wouldn't just use Min()

Comment: @AndyBursh: sorry, I'm still a bit confused why `Min()` won't do the trick?

Comment: I don't think it would work here as I wouldn't have a collection of things to iterate over. The testing and tracking of the best would take place during the generation. Of course, this is only the case when I don't want to store/care about storing all of the other generated items.